NetSuite Deposit Record with Cashback Sublist: Is there a way I can add 'Name'/'Entity' column field to the cashback sublist?
To allow the user to post a line to the AccPay/AccRec control GL account associated with a customer or supplier ledger account. Similar to the 'Other Deposit' sublist. Without a customer or supplier ledger account, any line posted to the AccPay/AccRec control GL account is shown in the '-NoSupplier-'/'-NoCustomer-' ledger in the Aged Report.
I tried with a UserEventScript and it adds a column but it doesn't load the 'Entity' list to select one, also after saving the record, it doesn't show the field on record view.
/**

@NApiVersion 2.1
@NScriptType UserEventScript
@NModuleScope Public

*/
define( [ 'N/record', 'N/log', 'N/ui/serverWidget' ], function ( record, log, serverWidget ) {
function beforeLoad ( context ) {
    var newRecord = context.newRecord;

    // Ensure the script runs only for deposit records
    if ( newRecord.type !== 'deposit' ) {
        log.debug( 'Record Type', 'Is Not Deposit' );
        return;
    }

    try {
        var form = context.form;

        // Add the 'custpage_cashback_entity' field to the 'cashback' sublist
        var cashbackSublist = form.getSublist( { id: 'cashback' } );

        if ( cashbackSublist ) {
            var entityField = cashbackSublist.addField( {
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                id: 'custpage_cashback_entity',
                label: 'NAME',
                source: 'entity' // This will source both customers and vendors
            } );
            entityField.updateDisplayType( {
                displayType: serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.ENTRY
            } );
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        log.error( 'Error', `Error adding 'Entity' field to Deposit Form's Cashback sublist', ${ e.toString() }` );
    }
}

return {
    beforeLoad: beforeLoad
};

} );

You would need an actual custom transaction column for this created via configuration not code. I don't believe the cash back sublist supports this though. I also cannot come up with a legal reason you would be able to make use of a customer/vendor column on the cash back sublist.
